# Executing an action before shutting down the node

Tags: ros2, node, rclpy

I want to stop my robot upon killing my process with SIGINT (CTRL+C). I registered a signal to handle SIGINT and typically this approach works. However in case the topic is not available/reachable CTRL+C does not have any effect and I have to kill the process manually.

```py
import signal

import rclpy  # ROS client library
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from rclpy.node import Node


class Tb3(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("tb3")

        self.cmd_vel_pub = self.create_publisher(
            Twist,
            "cmd_vel",
        )


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    tb3 = Tb3()
    print("Use CTRL+\\ if CTRL+C does not work")

    def stop_robot(sig, frame):
        print("stop")  # e.g., publish 0 velocity
        exit()

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, stop_robot)  # Stop on SIGINT
    rclpy.spin(tb3)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Background info:

- I used to catch `KeyboardInterrupt`, however I could not publish a message before shutdown using `KeyboardInterrupt`.
- The problem could be related to rcl library which does not react to my signal.
- This problem could be solved on the node listening on the `cmd_vel` by stopping the robot if no message is received after certain amount of time (like a watchdog). However I am searching for a solution on the publisher side.

Does someone have a solution/idea?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be exactly what you are looking for but this can help. You can try to implement a watchdog sort of implementation at the receiver side of your `cmd_vel` topic where in you can update a timer every time you receive a msg. let's say you didn't receive any msg within a specified amount of time then you may take appropriate decision which can be in this case sending 0 velocity and shutting down. Hope  this helps.

Comment: thanks tomrob, I added your idea to the question. I am searching for a client solution as you have anticipated :)